# Divider() not shown as it should be with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-navigationstack

I want to make a divider in white with some opacity (under the navigation view) but for a reason I don't know the `Divider()` isn't shown as it should be.

Here's a screenshot of the design:

[image]

And here's a screenshot when I run the code:

[image]

In the code, even in a full-white or red the `Divider()` isn't shown correctly.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            VStack {
                Divider()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white.opacity(0.18))
                ScrollView {
                    VStack {
                        // Content
                    }
                }
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
                .toolbar {
                    // Settings icon
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                        Text("Title")
                    }
                    // Add icon
                }
            }
            .background(Color("blue"))
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have an idea why? Thanks!

Comment: The code you posted does not match your screenshots. Also, you can't change the color of a Divider(). You can .overlay() it with a color, but most just use a Rectangle() with a frame height of 1, or however thick you want it.

Comment: I didn't know we couldn't change the color of a `Divider()`. Thanks for recommanding the `Rectangle()`, it works great. Next step: changing the color of the Status Bar (from black to white). Thanks again!

Comment: A ```Divider``` is already semi-transparent. So to give it a tint, you just have to apply a background to it: ```Divider().background(.red)```